# When is it possible to estimate the non-linearity error when approximating data with a linear model?

Tags: linear-model, error, approximation, nonlinearity

The most common form of linear regression estimates the best values of $\vec{\beta}$ and $\sigma^2$ assuming that data is sampled from a model $y = \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}$ where $\epsilon$ is a normally distributed error with variance $\sigma^2$.

In practice, a more accurate assumption is that $y = \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{x} + g(\vec{x}) + \vec{\epsilon}$ where $g$ is some unknown function with zero derivative at the origin. If we approximate this with a linear model as above, we can still get a good estimate of the values of $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$. My question is: when is it possible to 
have a reasonable estimate of the magnitude of $g(\vec{x})$ near the origin? Is it possible to say anything if I don't have enough data to recover the entire Hessian matrix for $g$?

Another way to state the same question: my problem is that the estimate of $\sigma^2$ becomes quite useless for estimating the approximation error if data is non-linear. For example, if the data actually comes from the distribution $y = x^2 +\epsilon$ (we could even set $\epsilon = 0$), our estimate for $\sigma^2$ will tend to zero as the number of data points increases (since we become more and more certain that the slope $\beta$ should be zero). What is a reasonable thing to replace it with?

I couldn't easily find a discussion of this topic anywhere. I am not a statistician, so explanations of what is the proper terminology to use when discussing this problem or what books discuss it would be helpful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Plot the residuals against $x$ and that should give you some idea.

Comment: You should be looking for discussion of the following two topics: (a) linear non-parametric models, such as `loess` and (b) generalized additive models.  Both of these provide ways to assess some non-linearity in  the context of a linear model.